# Put code into a variable

Tags: php, variables

How can I put a block of `php` into a variable? The code below is not working:

```
$test = "
        <?php
        session_start();
        $test = 'test'; 

        $_SESSION['test'] = $test;

        header("Refresh: 0;url=/");
        ?>
    ";
```

Comment: Why would like to do this

Comment: i want to save this to another created file with fwrite function

Comment: You have quotation marks (`"`) in your string, so the string ends at `header("`. You should escape it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using double quotes for the assignment the data inside is being interpreted. Use single quotes.

```
$test = '<?php
        session_start();
        $test = "test"; 
        $_SESSION["test"] = $test;
        header("Refresh: 0;url=/");
        ?>';
echo $test;
```

Output:

```
 <?php
        session_start();
        $test = "test"; 
        $_SESSION["test"] = $test;
        header("Refresh: 0;url=/");
        ?>
```

Comment: No matter which type of quote you use, you may find yourself at some point needing to use that same type of quote inside the string. If that happens, you'll have to either escape it like `\"` and `\'` or use concatenation.

Comment: @TecBrat with the double quotes though `$test` and `$_SESSION['test']` are also going to cause issues.